# What Percentage of Formulas in Propositional Logic is Satisfiable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $P_{n}$ be the set of all formulas in propositional logic with $n$ variables. Let then $Q_{n} \subset P_{n}$ be the maximal set of all non-equivalent formulas in propositional logic of length $n$.

More formally, $Q_{n}:=\hbox{argmax}_{|p_{n}|} \{p_{n} \subset P_{n} \land \forall i, j \in p_{n}: i \not \equiv j\}$

I haven't found any information about the percentage of formulas in $Q_{n}$ that is satisfiable, i.e. $\frac{|\{q_{n} | q_{n} \in Q_{n} \land \hbox{SAT}(q_{n})\}|}{|Q_{n}|}$.

Is it known what that number would be?

Comment: The question as stated doesn't really make sense, because both sets are infinite and the quotient is $\frac\infty\infty$.  It might work to ask about $P_{n,k}$, the set of formulas of length at most $k$ with at most $n$ variables.  This set is finite.  Then consider the fraction of those formulas that are satisfiable, and ask what happens to the fraction in the limit as $k$ increases without bound.

Comment: Hm, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I think the "non-equivalent" part is important: For example, $Q_{1}$ would be $\{x_1,\lnot x_1, True, False\}$ (since $x_1 \lor x_1 \equiv x_1$, or $x_1 \lor \lnot x_1 \equiv True$).

Comment: I edited the question to provide a clearer definition of $Q_{n}$.

Comment: There has been considerable work on questions like this for formulas (not identifying equivalent ones) in a standard format like conjunctive normal form. Google "SAT phase transitions" for sources.

Comment: @niplav the seminal paper in phase transitions is [Where the Really Hard Problems Are](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.97.3555) by Cheeseman, Kanefsky, Taylor.  It is very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you propose to consider only classes of *inequivalent* formulas, the answer is simple.  Exactly *one* formula is unsatisfiable, because any two unsatisfiable formulas are logically equivalent!

There are $2^{2^n}$ inequivalent formulas with $n$ variables.  (Consider the truth tables.  A truth table with $n$ variables has $2^n$ rows, and the rows may be filled in $2^{2^n}$ ways.)   So the answer is simply $$1-2^{-{2^n}}.$$

(Note that for your example of $n=1$, there are $2^{2^1} = 4$ formulas, and all but one $(\it{False})$ is satisfiable.)